# Filename to Extract

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Greetings hope everyone is well.

I would like to extract the filename in bash from the
following

```
User/ABC/CDE
User/ABC/CDE1
User/ABC/CDE2
User/ABC/CDE3
User/ABC/CDE4
```

as

```
CDE
CDE1
CDE2
CDE3
CDE4
```

I trying the following code

```
list1 = find User/ABC/ -iname "*CDE*" 

for lis in list1; do 
    filename =$(basename $lis)
    echo $filename 
done
```

Please let me know what is wrong here.
Thank you

Comment: Using GNU find to strip the starting path: `find ... -printf '%P\n'`. Alternatively: `find ... -exec basename {} \;` to strip all parent paths. Your shell code has many errors.

Comment: thank you for the correction. where do I apply these

Comment: `find User/ABC/ -iname "*CDE*" -printf '%P\n'` will print the list.

Comment: it is throwing error for that

Comment: However ```find User/ABC/ -iname "*CDE*" -exec basename {} \; ``` works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax errors. Please note the space. And to refer a variable, you need the prefix `$`

```
list1=$(find User/ABC/ -iname "*CDE*")
for lis in $list1; do
     filename=$(basename $lis);
     echo $filename 
done
```